# How do I numerically compute $I(X;CX+Y)$?

Tags: computational-statistics, information-theory, mutual-information

Given that $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\nu)$ for some $\nu\in(0,1)$, and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ are **independent** random variables. I want to compute the mutual information $I(X;CX+Y)$, where $C$ is some known non-random constant. Is there a simple way to approximate this numerically? Thanks.

Comment: is $C$ known or unknown?

Comment: known, edited my question -- thanks.